# Need SQL result from 3 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Hello!**

It's probably a simple question for the SQL Experts, Here are the tables i have:

```
**Table1 (Users):**
UserId -> 0,1,2...
UserName -> name1, name2, name3 ...

**Table2 (Actions):**
DealId -> 80,81,82...
BuyerId -> 0,1,2...
SellerId -> 2,3,4...
Amount -> 80,120,900...

**Table3 (Deals):**
DealId -> 80,81,82...
Dealname -> DealName1,DealName2...
UserId -> 0,1,2...
```

**And here is the result Table i need (from 3 tables):**

```
Column 1: Buyer Name(Users.UserName) with (Actions.BuyerId -> Users.UserId)
Column 2: Seller Name(Users.UserName) with (Actions.SellerId -> Users.UserId)
column 3: Deal Name(Deals.DealName) with (Deals.DealId -> 80 [known number])
column 4: Amount (Actions.Amount) with (Deals.DealId -> 80 [known number])
```

Of course i need to show **only** the results with the right DealId (80)..
Anyone can help??

I hope that's clear..

**Thank you!!**

Eran.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: This is not a "gimme teh codez" website.

Comment: If you can't help, Please don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 SELECT [Buyer].UserName, 
        [Seller].UserName, 
        [Deals].Dealname, 
        [Actions].Amount 
 FROM [Deals]
 LEFT JOIN [Actions] ON [Actions].DealID = [Deals].DealID
 LEFT JOIN [Users] AS [Seller] ON [Seller].UserID = [Actions].SellerID
 LEFT JOIN [Users] AS [Buyer] ON [Buyer].UserID = [Actions].BuyerId
 WHERE [Deals].DealID = 80
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Buyer.UsernName, Seller.UserName, Deals.Dealname, Action.Amount FROM Deals
LEFT JOIN Actions ON Actions.DealID=Deals.DealID
LEFT JOIN Users AS Seller ON Seller.UserID=Actions.UserID
LEFT JOIN Users AS Buyer ON Buyer.UserID=Buyer.UserID
WHERE Deals.DealID=80
```

Comment: This code is incorrect. Providing a `LEFT JOIN` on `Buyer.UserID = Buyer.UserID` is going to return incorrect results. Also - there IS no `Actions.UserID`.